# Test .net 6 fails on github action but passes locally

Tags: .net, testing, razor, github-actions, razor-pages

This test:

```
        [Test]
        public async Task GivenLinks_WhenDisplayingPage_TheTitlesShouldDisplay()
        {
            // Arrange
            var client = _factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
            {
                builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddScoped<ILinkRepository, TestLinkRepository>(serviceProvider =>
                    {
                        return new TestLinkRepository(_links, null);
                    });
                });
            })
                .CreateClient();

            //Act
            var defaultPage = await client.GetAsync("/public/links");
            var content = await HtmlHelpers.GetDocumentAsync(defaultPage);
            var title = content.QuerySelector("#title-links").TextContent;
            var subtitle = content.QuerySelector("#subtitle-links").TextContent;

            // Assert
            Assert.That(title.Trim(), Is.EqualTo("Liens"));
            Assert.That(subtitle.Trim(), Is.EqualTo("Amitiés Spirituelles"));
        }
```

Passes locally but fails on github Actions.
Do you know what I should do in order that it passes?

This is in the SetUp:

```
...
_factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
...
```

Comment: Install GitHub Actions build agent locally and you can reproduce the error. Don't merely trust your `dotnet test` results.

Comment: On which NuGet? I do not find GitHub Actions build agent nuget... If it is not a nuget, where can I install it?